# Kotlin: serialize Float element with 3 decimal places

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a data class like this:

```
import kotlinx.serialization.SerialName
import kotlinx.serialization.Serializable
import kotlinx.serialization.json.JsonElement

@Serializable
data class Event(
    @SerialName("name")
        val name: String? = "",
    @SerialName("speed")
        val speed: Float? = 0F,
    @SerialName("distance")
        val distance: Float? = 0F,
 )
```

I will use this API to serialize an Event object to a string. The requirement is to convert the speed value to one with three decimal places—for example, speed=51.129789f to 51.130 or 51.129 for simple. However, the distance value should not be converted.

```
Json{ encodeDefaults = true }.encodeToString(Event_object)
```

How could I do it?
Could I add some notation after `@SerialName("speed")` to give the format request?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a custom serializer for your field. Like:

```
@Serializable
data class Event(
    @SerialName("name") val name: String? = "",
    @Serializable(with = SpeedSerializer::class) val speed: Float? = 0F,
    @SerialName("distance") val distance: Float? = 0F,
 )

class SpeedSerializer : KSerializer<Float> {
    override val descriptor = PrimitiveSerialDescriptor("speed", PrimitiveKind.FLOAT)

    override fun deserialize(decoder: Decoder): Float {
        return decoder.decodeFloat()
    }

    override fun serialize(encoder: Encoder, value: Float) {
        encoder.encodeFloat((value * 1000).roundToInt() / 1000f)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! It is a good solution which meets the requirement. However, if the value is 12.1298f, the new value is 12.13f. How can we keep the value as 12.130 in the serialized string?

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to round of a number with long decimal numbers

**First**

```
    val num = 51.129789f 
    println("%.3f".format(num))
    //This will print 51.129
```

**Second**

```
    val df = DecimalFormat("#.###")
    df.roundingMode = RoundingMode.CEILING

    println(df.format(num))
```

Comment: "This will print 51.129." This is incorrect.

Comment: This is a tested code. How do u think that's incorrect?

Comment: Your claim that the first code example prints 51.129 is incorrect. If you're going to claim that you tested it, prove it. Because when I tested it, [it doesn't do what you say](https://tio.run/##y84vycnM@/8/rTRPITcxM08jsSi92ErBsagosdImuKQoMy/dTlOhmksBCMoScxTySnMVbBVMDfUMjSzNLSzTFMAyBUB1JTl5GkqqesZpSnpp@UW5iSUaQLWammB5ff2QjMxihfLMnByIWqgJXLX//wMA "Kotlin – Try It Online"). Also, please do not revert the edit removing the last line. It does not belong on this site.